# How to make ReplaceAll recognize what to be replaced in a situation like this?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, algebraic-manipulation

I'm a bit confused on how `ReplaceAll` works. For example

```
ReplaceAll[2x+2y, x+y -> 1]
```

just gives `2x+2y`. While of course

```
ReplaceAll[2(x+y),x+y -> 1]
```

Gives `2` as expected. Why Mathematica does not recognize that `2x+2y = 2(x+y)` so that the replacement should be applied? How can I make it replace in situations like this?

One remark, of course *in this situation* if I run `FullSimplify` first, then it turns `2x+2y` into `2(x+y)` and the replacement works. But I have encountered situations in which I was trying to simplify some complicated expression, it contained something like this `2x+2y`, but `FullSimplify` *didn't* factorize it, so that the replacement didn't work. I managed to construct a simple example, if we try

```
FullSimplify[Exp[I Pi (2x+2y+5)]]
```

we get back the same expression, then the replacement doesn't work.

I would therefore be interested in a more general solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `x + y -> 1` replace only one of the variables `x->1-y` or `y->1-x`, it does not matter which one, the result will be the same:

```
2 x + 2 y /. x + y -> 1

2 x + 2 y /. Solve[x + y == 1, y][[1]] // Expand
2 x + 2 y /. Solve[x + y == 1, x][[1]] // Expand
```

---

```
2 x + 2 y

2

2
```

It works with any expression:

```
Exp[I Pi (2 x + 2 y + 5)] /. Solve[x + y == 1, y][[1]] // FullSimplify
Exp[I Pi (2 x + 2 y + 5)] /. Solve[x + y == 1, x][[1]] // FullSimplify
```

---

```
-1

-1
```

Answer (score 4):

[`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) operates on the parts of the expression.

```
{2 x + 2 y, FullSimplify[Exp[I Pi (2 x + 2 y + 5)]], x + y} // 
  FullForm

(* List[Plus[Times[2, x], Times[2,y]], 
  Power[E, Times[Complex[0, 1], Pi, Plus[5, Times[2, x], 
   Times[2, y]]]], Plus[x, y]] *)
```

Note that `x + y`, i.e., `Plus[x, y]` does **not** appear in the `FullForm` of either of the first two expressions.

As a general rule (and as recommended by azerbajdzan), replacement rules should keep the LHS of the rule as simple as possible to more readily match subparts of the original expression.

Answer (score 3):

**New answer** based upon your revised question:

```
rep[f_] := 
 Expand[f] /. Plus[Times[a_, _Symbol], Times[b_, _Symbol]] :> a

2 x + 2 y // rep
```

2

```
2 (x + y) // rep
```

2

```
Exp[I Pi (2 a + 2 b + 5)] // rep
```

-1

**Old answer**

Either

```
2 x + 2 y /. {x :> 1, y :> 1}
```

4

```
2 (x + y) /. {x :> 1, y :> 1}
```

4

```
Exp[I Pi (2 x + 2 y + 5)] /. {x :> 1, y :> 1}
```

-1

Or, more generally,

```
rep[f_] := 
 Expand[f] /. Plus[Times[a_, _Symbol], Times[b_, _Symbol]] :> a b

Exp[I Pi (2 a + 2 b + 5)] // rep
```

-1

etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry, but I had made a mistake in the question, I'm replacing `x+y->1` instead of `x->1` and `y->1` individually, so that `ReplaceAll[2(x+y),x+y -> 1]` returns `2` and not `4`. But from your answer I guessed the following: `5 + 2 x + 2 y /. Plus[Times[a_, x_], Times[a_, y_]] :> a (x + y)` and it seems to work. Just one question, why do you use the _Symbol?

Comment: `_Symbol` stands for ANY symbol. So, for example, you could use `a` and `b` instead of `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is as follows:

```
rep = # /. s_Symbol /; Attributes[s] === {} -> 1 &;

rep@(2 x + 2 y)

(*4*)

rep@Exp[I Pi (2 a + 2 b + 5)]

(*-1*)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ReplaceAll` simply replaces pattern, not the value. And you have no x+y pattern in that expression.

Try `FullSimplify[2 x + 2 y, x + y == 1]`